# Grails redirects drop AWS host from URL

Tags: grails, redirect, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am having a really strange problem on my grails app, which is running on an Amazon EC2 instance.  All redirects are dropping the hostname.  Here's a demo controller:

```
class DemoController {
    def index = {
        redirect(action:test)
    }
    def test = {
        render "Hello World, this is a test"
    }
}
```

You can see the result of the problem redirect here.

Demo index: http://ec2-54-235-232-227.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8080/mpg5/demo/

Demo test: http://ec2-54-235-232-227.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8080/mpg5/demo/test

Note that the demo test action works as you would expect. It is only the index redirecting to it that is the problem.  This is happening to all redirects, but only on Amazon.  When I run this on localhost, there is no problem (of course there is no hostname to drop there either.)

Comment: Check your grails.serverURL setting in grails-app/conf/Config.groovy

Comment: You were correct - a mistaken version deleting the host was checked in earlier - guessing someone was trying to set it to a new value but forgot to finish!  I've accepted your answer below, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you don't have your production server URL setup correctly in your Config.groovy. Double check that you have it set properly.

```
// set per-environment serverURL stem for creating absolute links
environments {
    development {
        grails.logging.jul.usebridge = true
    }
    production {
        grails.logging.jul.usebridge = false
        // TODO: grails.serverURL = "http://www.changeme.com"
    }
}
```

Comment: The serverURL was incorrectly set, someone had checked in a version without the host, and now it all makes sense to me!  Thank you so much!